# How to solve that springboot3.2 and shardingsphere-jdbc-core5.4.1 snakeyaml method 'void <init>()' not found

Tags: spring-boot, snakeyaml, shardingsphere

2023/12/25 17:16:19.022 INFO  [x-transaction-id: ys-139956de696c4ca8bd706ce9e5ce2816] [tomcat-handler-4] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023/12/25 17:16:19.028 INFO  [x-transaction-id: ys-139956de696c4ca8bd706ce9e5ce2816] [tomcat-handler-4] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource : HikariPool-22 - Starting...
2023/12/25 17:16:19.029 INFO  [x-transaction-id: ys-139956de696c4ca8bd706ce9e5ce2816] [tomcat-handler-4] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool : HikariPool-22 - Added connection conn50: url=jdbc:h2:mem:config user=SA
2023/12/25 17:16:19.029 INFO  [x-transaction-id: ys-139956de696c4ca8bd706ce9e5ce2816] [tomcat-handler-4] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource : HikariPool-22 - Start completed.
2023/12/25 17:16:19.030 INFO  [x-transaction-id: ys-139956de696c4ca8bd706ce9e5ce2816] [tomcat-handler-4] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource : HikariPool-23 - Starting...
2023/12/25 17:16:19.036 INFO  [x-transaction-id: ys-139956de696c4ca8bd706ce9e5ce2816] [tomcat-handler-4] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool : HikariPool-23 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@2a513389
2023/12/25 17:16:19.037 INFO  [x-transaction-id: ys-139956de696c4ca8bd706ce9e5ce2816] [tomcat-handler-4] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource : HikariPool-23 - Start completed.
2023/12/25 17:16:19.037 INFO  [x-transaction-id: ys-139956de696c4ca8bd706ce9e5ce2816] [tomcat-handler-4] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource : HikariPool-24 - Starting...
2023/12/25 17:16:19.042 INFO  [x-transaction-id: ys-139956de696c4ca8bd706ce9e5ce2816] [tomcat-handler-4] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool : HikariPool-24 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@af5a9ec
2023/12/25 17:16:19.042 INFO  [x-transaction-id: ys-139956de696c4ca8bd706ce9e5ce2816] [tomcat-handler-4] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource : HikariPool-24 - Start completed.
2023/12/25 17:16:19.042 INFO  [x-transaction-id: ys-139956de696c4ca8bd706ce9e5ce2816] [tomcat-handler-4] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource : HikariPool-25 - Starting...
2023/12/25 17:16:19.047 INFO  [x-transaction-id: ys-139956de696c4ca8bd706ce9e5ce2816] [tomcat-handler-4] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool : HikariPool-25 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@392a56e9
2023/12/25 17:16:19.047 INFO  [x-transaction-id: ys-139956de696c4ca8bd706ce9e5ce2816] [tomcat-handler-4] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource : HikariPool-25 - Start completed.
jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Handler dispatch failed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.Representer: method 'void ()' not found
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1104)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)
at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
at com.ys.order.filter.MDCTraceFilter.doFilter(MDCTraceFilter.java:35)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
at org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter.doFilterInternal(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:109)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
at java.base/java.lang.VirtualThread.run(VirtualThread.java:309)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.Representer: method 'void ()' not found
at org.apache.shardingsphere.infra.util.yaml.representer.ShardingSphereYamlRepresenter.(ShardingSphereYamlRepresenter.java:42)
at org.apache.shardingsphere.infra.util.yaml.YamlEngine.marshal(YamlEngine.java:112)
at org.apache.shardingsphere.metadata.persist.service.config.global.NewPropertiesPersistService.persist(NewPropertiesPersistService.java:51)
at org.apache.shardingsphere.metadata.persist.NewMetaDataPersistService.persistGlobalRuleConfiguration(NewMetaDataPersistService.java:97)
at org.apache.shardingsphere.mode.metadata.NewMetaDataContextsFactory.persistDatabaseConfigurations(NewMetaDataContextsFactory.java:147)
at org.apache.shardingsphere.mode.metadata.NewMetaDataContextsFactory.create(NewMetaDataContextsFactory.java:102)
at org.apache.shardingsphere.mode.metadata.NewMetaDataContextsFactory.create(NewMetaDataContextsFactory.java:71)
at org.apache.shardingsphere.mode.manager.standalone.NewStandaloneContextManagerBuilder.build(NewStandaloneContextManagerBuilder.java:53)
at org.apache.shardingsphere.driver.jdbc.core.datasource.ShardingSphereDataSource.createContextManager(ShardingSphereDataSource.java:78)
at org.apache.shardingsphere.driver.jdbc.core.datasource.ShardingSphereDataSource.(ShardingSphereDataSource.java:66)
at org.apache.shardingsphere.driver.api.ShardingSphereDataSourceFactory.createDataSource(ShardingSphereDataSourceFactory.java:95)
at org.apache.shardingsphere.driver.api.yaml.YamlShardingSphereDataSourceFactory.createDataSource(YamlShardingSphereDataSourceFactory.java:167)
at org.apache.shardingsphere.driver.api.yaml.YamlShardingSphereDataSourceFactory.createDataSource(YamlShardingSphereDataSourceFactory.java:102)
at org.apache.shardingsphere.driver.jdbc.core.driver.DriverDataSourceCache.createDataSource(DriverDataSourceCache.java:52)
at org.apache.shardingsphere.driver.jdbc.core.driver.DriverDataSourceCache.lambda$get$0(DriverDataSourceCache.java:46)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1708)
at org.apache.shardingsphere.driver.jdbc.core.driver.DriverDataSourceCache.get(DriverDataSourceCache.java:46)
at org.apache.shardingsphere.driver.ShardingSphereDriver.connect(ShardingSphereDriver.java:53)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:121)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.(HikariPool.java:100)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:160)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:118)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:81)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:388)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:476)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:486)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForList(JdbcTemplate.java:536)
at com.ys.order.controller.TestController.test4(TestController.java:133)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:352)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:765)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:765)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
at com.ys.order.controller.TestController$$SpringCGLIB$$0.test4()
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:254)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:182)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:917)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:829)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089)
... 35 more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The reason why the old version of ShardingSphere cannot change the
   SnakeYAML version is that ElasticJob uses the old version of the
   SnakeYAML API. Therefore, only when ElasticJob makes changes and
   releases 3.0.4, ShardingSphere can make changes.
2. At the current stage, you need to compile this project manually and
   install the corresponding 5.4.2 snapshot version of ShardingSphere
   into the local maven repo through Maven's install goal, or deploy it
   into a private maven repo.